# dynamic oracle sql parent-child cursor insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, insert, cursors

I'd like to insert values to a parent TABLE_1 and a child TABLE_2 tables in a cursor. How can I do that? IF statement and its variables is just trying.

All columns are a constraint:
TABLE_1 constraints: PPRT_MANDANT_NR, PPRT_PRO_PROD_NR, PPRT_PRP_POSITION
TABLE_2 constraints: PATT_MANDANT_NR, PATT_PRO_PROD_NR, PATT_PRP_POSITION, PATT_ARE_REALARTNR

This code is actually working without error message but wrong results. I get just few rows to TABLE_2. I think my IF statement is wrong. Or dunno... Help me pls.

```
OPEN l_cursor FOR l_query;
  FETCH l_cursor
  BULK COLLECT INTO l_sucherg;
CLOSE l_cursor;

i := l_sucherg.FIRST;

WHILE i IS NOT NULL
 LOOP
  IF ( l_pro_mandant_nr <> l_sucherg (i).pro_mandant_nr
       OR l_pro_prod_nr <> l_sucherg (i).pro_prod_nr
       OR l_prp_position <> l_sucherg (i).prp_position)
       AND l_prp_are_realartnr <> l_sucherg (i).prp_are_realartnr
  THEN
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (PPRT_PKOT_SEQ,
                         PPRT_MANDANT_NR,
                         PPRT_PRO_PROD_NR,
                         PPRT_PRP_POSITION )
    VALUES (l_seq,
            l_sucherg (i).pro_mandant_nr,
            l_sucherg (i).pro_prod_nr,
            l_sucherg (i).prp_position );
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
   raise_application_error ( -20001, SQLERRM );
   END;
  ELSIF l_prp_are_realartnr <> l_sucherg (i).prp_are_realartnr
  THEN
   BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_2 (PATT_PKOT_SEQ,
                         PATT_MANDANT_NR,
                         PATT_PRO_PROD_NR,
                         PATT_PRP_POSITION,
                         PATT_ARE_REALARTNR)
    VALUES (l_seq,
            l_sucherg (i).pro_mandant_nr,
            l_sucherg (i).pro_prod_nr,
            l_sucherg (i).prp_position,
            l_sucherg (i).prp_are_realartnr );

    l_prp_are_realartnr := l_sucherg (i).prp_are_realartnr;
   EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
   raise_application_error ( -20001, SQLERRM );
   END;
  END IF;

 l_pro_mandant_nr := l_sucherg (i).pro_mandant_nr;
 l_pro_prod_nr := l_sucherg (i).pro_prod_nr;
 l_prp_position := l_sucherg (i).prp_position;

 i := l_sucherg.NEXT (i);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: It is really bad programming practice to capture errors and re-raise them with a common SQL code. Just let the errors fall through. This will allow calling code to use dbms_utility to find the exact line the error occurred, and also to trap specific errors by their SQLCODE.

Comment: Your if statements do not handle all conditions. if you intention was to process all statements, this won't do that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Brian! I found the problem finally. I got PATT_ARE_REALARTNR with more same values, so I added an dup_val_on_index exception to TABLE_2 with an update statement and handled the problem. :)